# css drop down menu not displaying in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have been having trouble displaying my css in safari 9.1. it has been working in Firefox, Chrome and Opera, i have inspected the CSS in safari and when toggled .open responds but not visible. it seems to be cut off by the navbar. If anyone can help that would be much appreciated [safari displayed incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoIKw.png) [others browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHDBc.png)

```css
 ul.responsive {
   overflow: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0px;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
}
 
ul.responsive.open{
   overflow: visible;
   height:250px;
   right: 0px;
   margin-top: 53px;
   margin-left: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="burger-nav"></a>
 <div class="container">
    <a class="logo" href="#">correct conversation</a>
    <ul class="main-nav">
       <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
       <li><a href="#location">Locations</a></li>
       <li><a href="#prices">Prices</a></li>
       <li><a href="#bookings">Bookings</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="responsive">
       <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
       <li><a href="#location">Locations</a></li>
       <li><a href="#prices">Prices</a></li>
       <li><a href="#bookings">Bookings</a></li>
       <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```